# Filter array of json having certain property Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I am just a beginner in swift.
i want to filter array of json objects having certain property and create new array of json from that.

my array is :

```
[{
  "marked" : 4,
  "attempted" : true,
  "correct" : 4,
  "subject" : 1,
  "status" : true,
  "question" : 550,
  "answer" : 34256,
  "time" : 23,
  "score" : 10,
  "chapter" : 26
}, {
  "marked" : 1,
  "attempted" : true,
  "correct" : 1,
  "subject" : 1,
  "status" : true,
  "question" : 566,
  "answer" : 34317,
  "time" : 33,
  "score" : 14,
  "chapter" : 26
}, {
  "marked" : 4,
  "attempted" : true,
  "correct" : 1,
  "subject" : 1,
  "status" : true,
  "question" : 590,
  "answer" : 34276,
  "time" : 33,
  "score" : 15,
  "chapter" : 26
}]
```

i want an array in which `marked` and `correct` have same values.

How can i do that in swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've converted this to array with objects, you can simply use.

```
myArray.filter { $0.marked == $0.correct }
```

If it's just dictionary, you can try to seek their values by key

```
myArray.filter { $0["marked"]! == $0["correct"]! }
```